# How to document/assert when inheritance induces a precondition for some final types only

Tags: c++, inheritance, doxygen, design-by-contract, preconditions

Consider this simple base class `Foo` having a function `foo` calling a pure virtual function `foo_`, documented with Doxygen :

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    /** \brief This function logs x and does the job */
    void foo(double x);
  protected:
    /** \brief This function does the job */
    virtual void foo_(double x) = 0;
};

void Foo::foo(double x)
{
  std::clog << "'Foo::foo(double x)' is called with x = " << x << std::endl;
  this->foo_(x);
}
```

I have no precondition to document for this abstract class.

Now, consider a derived class `Bar` on which a precondition exists to work correctly :

```
class Bar : public Foo
{
  public:
    /**
     * \brief This function does the job
     * \pre   x must be greater or equal to 0
     */
    virtual void foo_(double x);
};

void Bar::foo_(double x)
{
  assert(x >= 0.0 && "PRE: x can't be negative");
  // Do the job
}
```

Now, I have a precondition on x when I call `foo_`, which is called by `foo`. Then, I have a precondition on `foo` depending on the final type.

Some questions :

1. Should I add the precondition in `Foo::foo` regardless of the final type ? It looks logical if the user never knows the final type when he uses the class. But the user can also have another class `Baz` derived from `Foo` without any precondition, and call explicitly `Baz::foo(double)` with negative values. It shouldn't be a matter.
2. In my notion of polymorphism, the class `Foo` doesn't have to know anything about his children, then the precondition can't be there. But the user of the mother class doesn't have to know the children to use the class. How to solve this contradiction ?
3. Is there a specific(/best) way to document this kind of thing with Doxygen ?

Comment: Assume your base class is something like a formula, and you derive two classes implementing say `cos` and `sqrt`, where the first one can handle all arguments, the second only positive ones. It doesn't make sense then to restrict the argument to the base class. On the other hand, the derived class that can't handle some values should not crash the program, so I wouldn't use `assert` but a more graceful error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule of using contracts in presence of inheritance is:

1. Preconditions can only get weaker in descendants.
2. Postconditions can only get stronger in descendants.

This guarantees that a client of an ancestor class is not affected by any implementation provided by a descendant, because this client does not necessary know about existence of such a descendant and it should be able to access members declared in the ancestor class freely even if at run-time the corresponding expression is dynamically bound to an object of the descendant class.

This works fine in most situations. But in your example the ancestor class has a precondition `true` and the descendant class has a stronger precondition. There are several approaches to deal with that:

1. Lift the stronger precondition to the ancestor class. Even if implementation there deals with all possible cases, certain scenarios may expect a non-trivial precondition and clients have to deal with that.
2. Change implementation of the descendant class so that it handles all cases and remove the stronger precondition altogether.
3. Avoid redeclaration of the member in question either by adding a new method with the strong precondition to the ancestor class or by using a different method in the descendant class, so that it has nothing to do with the original one.
4. Use abstract contracts. Instead of specifying a contract directly, it can be a call to a virtual function defined in the ancestor class. In your example the function will return `true`. A descendant class can redefine this function and add the checks it needs to. The main drawback of this solution is that a client will have to check the abstract precondition before it calls the method to make sure it does not violate it.

The final decision depends on the concrete scenario.

Comment: Nice overview. It makes me think that the problem is more located in the precondition itself. I really like the 4th possibility. Thanks !